# c++ counter type that does not need a lock for increment

Tags: c++, multithreading

I need a small counter (up to 10).

I don’t want to use atomic (because the overhead of atomic).

Which type can i use for this?

I might doing premature optimization , but unfortunately I cannot simulate the full production env right now (multi-threading env).

Running on Ubuntu x86

Comment: If you don't want to use some locking mechanism (atomic included), you can't really rely on the values.

Comment: If you're accessing it from multiple threads, you need the guarantees atomic provides. That overhead is what makes it *work*.

Comment: Can i use byte and dont worried about multi thread increment

Comment: You are doing premature **pessimization**, if you are in a multithreaded context atomic types are as fast as you will get.

Comment: @user1495181: Not portably. This *is* premature musing: you're making unnecessary complications and sacrifices of correctness for the sake of performance improvement you don't even know exists. Why ask a question if every response you simply reply with what you wish were true?

Comment: Just take the hit and have a lock - that way you can guarantee that it will work! Also your code may work for quite a while but the problem will at some point come up and bite you.

Comment: you do premature optimization (or at least try it). why do you think, you can do better than the gurus implementing the standard libs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Atomic is the right thing to use and the fastest way to do it. If your architecture can do atomic updates in a single instruction then that's how the atomic types will be implemented.

Answer (score 0):

If you only write to the counter from only one thread, and all other threads only read the counter, then on most platforms you can use an `int`, as most CPUs have an atomic increment instruction and writing the new value back to memory is also going to be atomic.

However, the standard doesn't guarantee this. If you want guaranteed atomicity, you need to use atomics. There's not much overhead doing so, since the compiler is smart enough to know whether it needs explicit locking or not for the increment operation and thus avoid overhead.

Comment: Atomicity is necesary for correctness, but you're lacking ordering and visibility.

Comment: I don't think on most CPU's the operation will be atomic. It's an increment, not a simple read. Even if the variable is already loaded in a registry, I don't see how it can be safe.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore An INC instruction is atomic on x86 (AFAIK). Since the value is only increased by 1, does it matter what the previous value was? Whatever it was, it will be increased by 1. Shouldn't that mean that ordering won't matter?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore Nope, forget it. I just figured out why this can't work :-P

Comment: @LuchianGrigore OK, I think the answer should now actually represent reality.